# The implications on memory usage of using & in a range for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory

I'm trying to wrap my head around memory in C++. I've read that using & in a loop saves us time on heap allocation and deallocation and therefore should be used whenever possible. I'm looking at a leetcode problem I've just done, and not only does using & in the loop have no impact on runtime - it also seems to negatively impact memory usage.

I was under the impression that if we omit the & in a loop, C++ will create an object for every iteration. Why then does it not seem to help? Is this specific to this problem and in what circumstances is it beneficial?

The code and problem I'm referring to are below:)

```
class Solution {
public:
    int arraySign(vector<int>& nums) {
        int product=1;
        for(auto i:nums){ // vs auto& i:nums
            if(i>0){
                continue;
            }
            else if(i==0) return 0;
            else product*=-1;
        }
        return product;
    }
};
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/sign-of-the-product-of-an-array/

Comment: @drescherjm Of course an `int` also needs to be copied. It's just that `sizeof(int)` is typically smaller or equal to `sizeof(int*)`, and fits into a register.

Comment: What I meant was an int does not have an internal pointer to some heap memory to copy like a std::string

Comment: If you use the `&` it will make a reference for every iteration. Without it you make a copy for every iteration. I would expect the difference to negligeble when dealing with an `int`. When dealing with more complex object the difference can be huge.

Comment: you arent modifiying `i` in the loop nor are you taking its adress, ie in your code there is no observable difference between a copy and a reference and I bet the compiler knows that

Comment: Small, trivially copyable types like `int` are better copied by value, since they fit in a register (unless you intend to modify the originals, then it needs to be by reference.)  Passing by reference is a win when copying is expensive (suppose instead of ints you had a vector of vectors, then each copy would be an allocation, etc.)  For ints, a reference may even add overhead of an indirection, though I'd trust the optimizer to eliminate it in cases like this.

Comment: @PatrickEllis What you say only applies to heap-allocated objects. ints aren't heap allocated, they're just primitives so there's no point in taking the loop var by reference unless you plan to modify it. How are you measuring speed, anyway? I wouldn't trust LC -- I wouldn't be surprised if random scheduling delays and so forth create larger differences than whether these ints are by-reference or by-value, especially since the compiler may well generate identical code both ways.